# MFC ugly menu font Windows 7

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing an application using Visual Studio 2010 and MFC. When I create application with MFC wizard menu font is somehow ugly.

Any ideas how to fix this? Here's an example and there seems to be the same ugly menu font.
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2010/06/01/~/media/ECG/visualstudiomagazine/Images/2010/06/0601vsm_F2Win7NativeDev1_hires.ashx

Comment: I'm sorry, where's the ugly font in that picture???

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you change default theme and font of the windows and check how it appears.

Comment: My Windows 7 is running default theme actually.